# Parse content from a file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to parse a file with the following contents and display it in a table. The problem is that I'm only able to get the first lease stanza. I'm not sure how to get the rest of them? Any ideas?

INPUT:

```
# The format of this file is documented in the dhcpd.leases manual page.
# This lease file was written by isc-dhcp-V3.0.3b1

lease 192.168.98.25 {
  starts 5 2012/10/05 21:18:41;
  ends 5 2012/10/05 22:48:15;
  tstp 5 2012/10/05 22:18:41;
  binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 78:d6:f0:c1:7f:b5;
  uid "\001x\326\360\301\177\265";
}
lease 192.168.10.1 {
  starts 5 2012/10/04 12:23:23;
  ends 5 2012/10/05 22:48:15;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 56:a3:f0:d1:75:b5;
  uid "\001x\326\360\301\177\265";
}
....
....
```

OUTPUT:

```
 HW Address  |start time  | end time | IP 
 78:d6:f0:c1:7f:b5 | 2012/10/05 21:18:41 | 2012/10/05 22:48:15 | 192.168.98.25
 56:a3:f0:d1:75:b5 | 2012/10/04 12:23:23 | 2012/10/05 22:48:15 | 192.168.10.1
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$readfile = file('/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.leases',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$arstring = implode(" ",$readfile);

$regex=array();
preg_match_all("(lease\s*([0-9.]+)\s*{\s*starts\s*.?\s*([0-9/\s:]*).?\s*ends\s*.?\s*([0-9/\s:]*).*ethernet\s*([\w:]*))", $arstring, $regex,PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Which gives me:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => lease 192.168.98.25 {   starts 5 2012/10/05 21:18:41;   ends 5 2012/10/05 22:18:41;   tstp 5 2012/10/05 22:18:41;   binding state free;   hardware ethernet 78:d6:f0:c1:7f:b5;   uid "\001x\326\360\301\177\265"; } lease 192.168.98.25 {   starts 5 2012/10/05 22:54:15;   ends 5 2012/10/05 23:54:15;   binding state active;   next binding state free;   hardware ethernet 78:d6:f0:c1:7f:b5;   uid "\001x\326\360\301\177\265"; } lease 192.168.98.25 {   starts 5 2012/10/05 22:54:16;   ends 5 2012/10/05 23:54:16;   binding state active;   next binding state free;   hardware ethernet 78:d6:f0:c1:7f:b5
        [1] => 192.168.98.25
        [2] => 2012/10/05 21:18:41
        [3] => 2012/10/05 22:18:41
        [4] => 78:d6:f0:c1:7f:b5
    )
```

Comment: Haven't you already got the data?

Comment: strange that you don't have the neither start/end delimiters nor modifiers in your pattern. have you tried: `preg_match_all("/your pattern here/mx"`?

Comment: i--, I tried using the "/" delimiters but that made it worse; the function returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP well so I can't give you the exact code, but if you turn this into a substitution and then execute it in a loop, substituting a blank for the matched portion until there is nothing left to match, that may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, that I eventually figured out, was that I wasn't escaping the . and / modifiers.

This is my working regex:

```
$reg_str = '/(lease\s*([0-9\.]+)\s*{\s*starts\s*.?\s*([0-9\/\s:]*).?\s*ends\s*.?\s*([0-9\/:\s\w]*);[\r\n\s\w;]*ethernet\s*([\w:]*);?[\w\s\\\"0-9\s\r]*;?\s*[\w\-]*\s*"?([\w-]*)"?;?\s*})/ims';
preg_match_all($reg_str, $arstring, $leases, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Thank you all for your help.